# Method Post or Session

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to pass data from a table to a field form 
this is the js code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var y = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".coll").on("click", function() {
              window.location = '<?php echo site_url("inscription/"); ?>';
</script>
```

and this is the part of the table (formation.php)

```html
<tr class='clickable-row'>
  <td id="num1" class="coll">
    <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'titre_module_'.$i,true); ?>
  </td>

  <td id="num2" class="coll">
    <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'desc_module_'.$i,true);  ?>
  </td>
  <td class="coll">
    <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'duree_'.$i,true);  ?>
  </td>
  <td class="coll">
    <?php $date_session =  wpautop(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'date_module_'.$i,true));
      echo $date_session;
     ?>
  </td>
  <td class="coll">
    <?php $date_session2 =  wpautop(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'sess2_'.$i,true));
      echo $date_session2;
     ?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and this is the field of the form (inscription.php)

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label title="Intitulé du module">Intitulé du module</label>
  <input type="text" name="intlmod" class="form-control" placeholder="Intitulé du module">
</div>
```

So I want when I click on a TD it redirect me to the form page with the field already full

Comment: Your js is missing some closing brackets `});`. Also what is your issue/question? ("I want ..." is none of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do it using get or post or session and you dont have to use JS. Here is the example format using http get method and urlencode.

```
<table>
<tr>
        <td id="num1"  class="coll"><a href="inscription.php?value=<?php echo urlencode(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'titre_module_'.$i,true)); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'titre_module_'.$i,true); ?></a></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

In your inscription.php page  use below code

```
       <div class="form-group">
<label title="Intitulé du module">Intitulé du module</label>
                <input type="text" name="intlmod" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value = urldecode($_POST['value']); ?>" >

        </div>
```